# Create this type of view in drupal7

Tags: 7, views

I am using latest drupal 7 and views. I have created a vocabulary and i have created terms under it. Each term has 2 levels sub terms under it.  Using views i wanted to create a drop down of all the base level terms and when select the base level terms from drop down all the sub level terms must be listed .. is this possible in views??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm waiting for this one, too. [Conditional Fields](https://drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) module.
But it's not yet available in D7.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the [Hierarchical Select](http://drupal.org/project/hierarchical_select) module.

> This module defines the "hierarchical_select" form element, which is a greatly enhanced way for letting the user select items in a hierarchy.
>
> Hierarchical Select has the ability to save the entire lineage of a selection or only the "deepest" selection. You can configure it to force the user to make a selection as deep as possible in the tree, or allow the user to select an item anywhere in the tree. Levels can be labeled, you can configure limit the number of items that can be selected, configure a title for the dropbox, choose a site-wide animation delay, and so on. You can even create new items and levels through Hierarchical Select!